# How to identify the subviews (imageviews) addeded to the UIButton in UIAutomation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I have a `UIButton` and the button `background` is set to an `image`. Added
an `image view` on the top right corner of the button and I set it
to different image when the button is clicked to show the selection.

When I try to `automate` this using `instruments`. I don’t see any `subviews`
(`image views`) in the `UIAutomator`.`logElementTree()`method does not show
any `image views`.

How to identify the `image views` added as `subview` in the `UIButton`?

Here is the code.

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 100, 100);
 [button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“testImage.png”] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
 imageview.frame = CGRectMake(70,30,20,20);
 [button addSubview:imageview];
```

Answer (score 2):

**You have to set the accessibilityEnabled & accessibilityLabel.**

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 100, 100);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.accessibilityEnabled = YES;
button.accessibilityLabel =@"My Button";

[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@“testImage.png”] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

imageview.accessibilityEnabled = YES;
imageview.accessibilityLabel = @"My Image";

imageview.frame = CGRectMake(70,30,20,20);
[button addSubview:imageview];
```

[image]

[Refer this tutorial](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation)

Answer (score 1):

Sweet Angel's answer is enough if you have a single `UIImageView` subview. However, I would suggest using `tag`s to identify subviews.

```
imageView.tag = 1346;//Any arbitrary number (I am unsure if there are any limitations to the values you can use, but all 4 digit numbers work fine for me).
```

Then to get the imageView:

```
UIImageView* imageView = (UIImageView*)[button viewWithTag:1346];
```

That's it.

Comment: I saw your edit now. I have never worked with `UIAutomation`, so I am unsure whether this serves your needs. I apologize.

Comment: Correction: Sweet Angel's answer is enough if you have multiple UIImageView subviews. because he/she is accessing 'sender.subviews', not a single one.

Comment: I said single because in their code, there is no way to differentiate if multiple `UIImageView`s are added to the superView in question (`UIButton` here). Sure, conditions can be added to make sure (like checking the image, frame, etc). The `tag` on the other hand gives you the specific view you are looking for.

Comment: Also, don't just access using the viewWithTag. including a validation will be more better. example: UIImageView* imageView = [[button viewWithTag:1346] isKindOfAClass:[UIImageView class]]?(UIImageView*)[button viewWithTag:1346]:nil;

Comment: @Ramshad, your code is correct, but redundant if you have set unique tags on your views, and are sure the view with tag is `UIImageView`. However, it does not hurt to add validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify imageview on button taped, try following code :

```
- (IBAction)didTapButton:(UIButton *)sender
{
    for (id view in sender.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            NSLog(@"Image view captured.....");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to identify the subview (imageview ) added to the UIButton in the UIAutomation not in iOS.